# How to modify every value of a row in a table using shell function?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

Need to modify one row in every column in a table. This is done by a function called from the shell. Need to use sqlplus to get values from table to modify, call function on values in shell, then insert the modified values back to the table. Was planning on using a cursor to iterate through the table, but it seems from what I've read that the cursor does not persist between calls to sqlplus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, your actual data manipulation logic is written in shell.
One possible solution for this use case can be,

1. You read meta data of the table (select column_name, column_id from
   all_tab_columns where table_name = <your_table>),
2. Keep this metadata at shell side.
3. Create a procedure to retrieve entire row from the table for a given <row_identifier>.
4. Create another procedure to perform 'save' operation with input parameters -<column_name>, <column_value> and <row_identifier>. This procedure can be invoked in a loop in-case there are multiple columns modified for a given row.

Comment: Didn't have enough space on shell side to store ROWID for each entry, ended up making a table on sql side with the data from rows I was looking to change, a unique identifier from each, and a row with an iterated number so I could do a for loop on shell side and cycle through them. Marking as correct answer though as this could help someone with similar question.